# Posting data associated with dynamically created html elements mvc5

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

Im developing a mvc5 application. In a view i dynamically generate html elements(textboxes and dropdownlists) using a returned json result and jquery. Now what i want to do is posting the selected data id's from ddls and entered texts in textboxes to server. Both id's and texts are saved in database in nvarchar format.  The number of ddls and textboxes generated dynamically is varying based on json result.

This is the json result

```
 var x = db.ItemTemplates.Where(a => a.MainGroupId == mnId).Where(a => a.SubGruopId == sbId).FirstOrDefault();
        var ids = new List<int> { x.Atribute1, x.Atribute2, x.Atribute3, x.Atribute4 };
 var y = db.Atributes.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.AtributeId)).Select(g => new
            {
                Name = g.AtributeName,
                Options = g.atributeDetails.Where(w=>w.AtributeDetailId!=null).Select(z => new 
                {
                    Value=z.AtributeDetailId,
                    Text=z.AtDetailVal
                })
            });
```

View briefly

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Save", "Item"))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.MainGrpId, new SelectList(ViewBag.mnGrpList,      "MainGroupId", "MainGroupName"), " Select a MainGroup", new { Class = "form-  control", title = "", style = "width:175px;height:30px; margin-top:6px;" })

    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SubGrpId, new SelectList(ViewBag.sbGrpList, "SubGroupId", "SubGroupName"), " Select a SubGroup", new { Class = "form-control", title = "", style = "width:175px;height:30px; margin-top:6px;" })

    <div id="ss" class="col-md-6">

    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
```

}

Jquery

```
var ss = $('#ss');
$('#SubGrpId').change(function () {
    $('#ss').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FillItem", "Item")', // dont hard code your url's
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { MnId: $('#MainGrpId').val(), SbId: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
        success: function (y) {
            $.each(y, function (l, u) {
                // add the label
                var name = u.Name;
                var label = $('<label></label>').text(name).attr('for', name);
                ss.append(label);
                if (u.Options.length==0) {
                    // There is only one item and its for generating a textbox
                    var input = $('<input>').attr({ type: 'text', id: name, name: name });
                    ss.append(input);
                } else {
                    // Its a select
                    var select = $('<select></select>').attr({ id: name, name: name });
                    // add each option
                    $.each(u.Options, function (i, option) {
                        select.append($('<option></option>').val(option.Value).text(option.Text));
                    })
                    ss.append(select);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("something wrong");
        }
    });
});
```

ItemModel (6 string type properties for ddls selected and textboxes entered values, only few fields of those 6 will be utilized while saving, sequence is not relevant)

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public int MainGrpId { get; set; }

    public int SubGrpId { get; set; }

    public string Field01 { get; set; }
    public string Field02 { get; set; }
    public string Field03 { get; set; }
    public string Field04 { get; set; }
    public string Field05 { get; set; }
    public string Field06 { get; set; }

 }
```

ViewModel(incomplete)

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int MainGrpId { get; set; }

    public int SubGrpId { get; set; }
}
```

Could anyone please guide me on how to organize the viewmodel to capture dynamic html elements and how to do the save functionality.

Comment: Who is this Jason guy?

Comment: have you heard of Partial Views?

Comment: @ Arijit Mukherjee, Yes i  am using it also.. But for this scenario i didn't use it. Do i have to use it here?

Comment: I was curious about what you were trying to do in your last question  :). The code is generating `name` attributes based on the `AtributeName` property so you cannot bind to any model as is. Rather than `var name = u.Name;` you would need to use `var name = Field01;` (and `Field02` for the next iteration etc) if your POST method is `List<Item>`

Comment: @developerbmw, oops sorry i noted it now. Will edit it :)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Yes it was very difficult for me to present that quetion in a understandable way.. :) Im using 'name = u.Name;' for labels also. How can i repalce it with 'var name=Field01' then in next iteration to 'Field02'. Do i have to write separate scripts for that. How can i organize the json data structure to reflect that. Could you pls help me with this..

Comment: I would use `var label = u.Name` and `var label = $('<label></label>').text(label).attr('for', name);` for the label bit. Then you could use `var name = 'Field0' + l;` which will generate `Field01`, `Field02` etc. But I suspect you going to run into more problems in the future :). Also you need to add the signature of the method your posting to (I have just assumed its has `List<Item> model`)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, ok give me few mins. i'll try it and let you know :)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, yes that worked. You saved me. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Only temporarily :) Cant be certain exactly what your doing (I assume this is associated with dynamically generated forms) but I can be certain that your design is wrong.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Fortunately there is only one thing remaining with this current Master form im developing. Now im struggling with that issue also. In few mins i'll be posting that too. I hope i can go to a different new form after that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92790/discussion-between-isuru-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code is giving the form elements a `name` attribute equal to the `AtributeName` property of your query which does not relate to your model. The `name` attributes need to be `name="Field01"`, `name="Field02"` etc.

Change you script to

```
var ss = $('#ss');
$('#SubGrpId').change(function () {
  $('#ss').empty();
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("FillItem", "Item")', // dont hard code your url's
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { MnId: $('#MainGrpId').val(), SbId: $(this).val() },
    success: function (y) {
      $.each(y, function (l, u) {
        // define the name attribute for the form controls
        var name = 'Field0' + (1 + l); // generates Field01, Field02
        // add the label
        var label = u.Name;
        var label = $('<label></label>').text(label).attr('for', name);
        ss.append(label);
        ....
```

Your form controls will now bind to a POST method which has a parameter `Item` - e.g. `public ActionResult Edit(Item model)`